# How to make my WPF application full screen

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, taskbar

I have been building a small WPF application that includes a media player. I am almost finished except for one part, Making the player full screen. I have gotten to the point to where I have the Windows Taskbar hidden, and the player is covering everything, except where the taskbar was. So the player is full screen except for where the taskbar would normally be, you just see a part of the desktop background.

```
private void Full_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    Taskbar.Hide();
    player.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
    controlPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;//hides media controls
    player.Height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight + 200;//I tried to set the height to fill the entire screen
    Full.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;//hides full screen control           //Im aware that may be too large of an increase but I
    CloseFull.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;//shows exit control            //wanted to see if it would work at all

}
```

Comment: you tried to set maxheight and then height?

Comment: Hi, if Nawed's answer solves the problem, please mark it as "Accepted" even if you found an alternate solution. You can also post your alternate solution as an answer to your own question, to help others who want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to hide the taskbar ?

This should be enough:

```
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
Topmost = true;
```

Comment: It was a media player, I just wanted to make it full screen. I found a VLC Player Plugin and used it instead, it works great now.